# Changing color with jquery removes hover color?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So i have:

```css
#selection_menu .secondary_options button:hover { color: #000066; }
```

and it works great on my site..

When one of these buttons is clicked, however, i run a javascript function that contains:

```
$('button').css("color","#FFFFFF");
if(!$sameTile)
    $($tileSelector).css("color","#000066");
```

So that when the button is clicked, the highlight color sticks when the mouse is moved away.

The problem i am having is that after this is run for the first time, the buttons stop changing color when highlighting. How can i get around this? Or is this normal behavior?

I am trying to add a class and i can't get it to work: http://jsfiddle.net/sUKkb/1/

Some more of my code:
index: http://pastebin.com/7gYu9YG8
css: http://pastebin.com/Jz1bvzrr

Or this might be more helpful: http://staging.easyzag.com/style.css

view-source:http://staging.easyzag.com/index.php?section=drink

Comment: If the button is already #000066, what color do you WANT it to change to when hovered over again?

Comment: @torazaburo I want the other buttons (there are 20) to still turn #000066 when highlighted

Comment: Just FYI, if you're going to use jQuery, you need to specify it in your jsFiddle (it's set to use Mootools by default).

Comment: yeah i realized that now, thanks! never used jsfiddle much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is (generally) what you're after:

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sUKkb/5/

HTML:

```
<button class="not-sticky">Hello</button>
```

JS:

```
$('button').on('click', function(e){
    $(this).removeClass('not-sticky').addClass('sticky-state');
});
```

Note, this does require a relatively new version of jQuery (1.7+). You could also use:

```
$('button').live('click', function(e){
    $(this).removeClass('not-sticky').addClass('sticky-state');
});
```

or

```
$('button').click(function(e){
    $(this).removeClass('not-sticky').addClass('sticky-state');
});
```

for older versions of jQuery.

Comment: I am using 1.7.2 so that should be fine, the problem i am having is $('button') does not seem to be affecting any of my buttons..

Comment: Can you elaborate? The updated fiddle (notice the version number) I link to **does** change the font color on the button "on click."

Comment: your fiddle does, but in my code there must be something keeping it from selecting or something.. i have posted the complete code i am working from, inside my document ready function i am trying to add the class notsticky to all buttons to begin, and it is not adding to any of them

Comment: If you want, I can step through it on something like Collabedit. SO discourages "chatty" Q&A exchanges.

Comment: yeah that would be awesome - i've never used it i will sign up right now - edit: didn't realized it costed money, is there anything like this that is free?

Comment: Collabedit is free. Just go here (I started a new document): http://collabedit.com/detds

Comment: whenever you see this - its all working great except that it will not pick up the style from my style sheet for .not-sticky which is weird because i used an inspector and it does have the class.. but when it changes to sticky-state it picks up the color styling

Comment: It's likely a specificity issue - the more specific CSS rule always wins. In the event two selectors are equally-specific, last rule applied wins.

Comment: I eneded up figuring it out. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

The issue here is that your jQuery is adding an inline style which will override the rule from your CSS. The other issue is `$('button').css('color','#000666')` is going to apply inline styles to **ALL** buttons.

I would suggest adding a rule in your CSS for the defaults and the sticky state like this:

```
button { color:#fff }
button:hover { color:#fff }
.sticky-state { color:#000066 }
```

Then in your jQuery you do this instead of what you're doing:

```
`$(/*add your selector here*/).addClass('.sticky-state');
```

Comment: alright i will try that - thanks! Note to self: read up on inline styles

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work.. i have $('.sticky-state').removeClass('sticky-state'); $($tileSelector).addClass('sticky-state'); but it seems like this is not doing anything at all

Answer (score 0):

Try this;
in your CSS;

```
.new_class{ 
   color:#000066 
}
```

in your JS

```
$('button').css("color","#FFFFFF");
if(!$sameTile){
    $($tileSelector).removeClass()('.your_previous_class');
    $($tileSelector).addClass('.new_class');
}
```

or you may try

```
$($tileSelector).css({ 'color':'#000066' });
```

here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sUKkb/2/ (without class)

and this one http://jsfiddle.net/sUKkb/3/ (with class)

and this one http://jsfiddle.net/sUKkb/4/ using ID instead of class to make buttons unique

And I think, what you want is a toggle solution like the fiddle below;

http://jsfiddle.net/sUKkb/7/

Comment: it seems like my addClass isnt working on anything.. to start i put $('button').addClass('not-sticky'); in my ready function to make it start with them all one color, and it is just loading with the default black still..

Comment: OK.. add whatever you tried so far on http://jsfiddle.net/ as a demo, save it and give us the link to work on.

Comment: i added a basic test and to my main post

Comment: so it just needed a class to start out? did you change anything else?

Comment: no need for class or id. It works even without class. Just use `<button>Hello</button>`

Comment: hmm why wasn't mine working when you first saw it? im going to post some more of my actual code if you dont mind looking at it, I still can't get it working

Comment: alright.. check my edit: line 77 is where i try to add the class

Answer (score 0):

you can do it without jquery if that's giving you trouble.

add an onmouseover and an onmouseout handler for the hover effect and add an onclick that first cancels the onmousover and onmouseout and then sets the desired color.

Comment: the problem i see with this is that i need it to go back to the original if a different button is clicked - if that makes sense?